# "He/she is the first to..." vs. "he/she was the first to..."

Tags: grammar, past-simple, present-simple

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> Neil Armstrong **is** the first man to step on the Moon surface.
>
> Neil Armstrong **was** the first man to step on the Moon surface.

Are both perfectly grammatical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They would both be grammatically correct (but write Moon's surface instead of Moon surface). The first sentence is in the present tense; the second one is in the past tense. There's kind of a nuanced difference that using the present tense might imply he stepped on the Moon recently (as if you're just reacting to it), or it could imply that no one else has done it since. Whereas using the past tense implies that it happened a long time ago. But he technically still 'is the first person to step on the moon', because nobody can go back and do it before him. So it's not grammatically incorrect to use the present tense, it just implies something different.

Edit: I've just realised 'he is the first person...' also implies he's still alive. So it would be incredibly unusual to use present tense here.

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence is grammatically correct, but the first one is not. The first one would not be correct because Neil Armstrong stepped on the moon in the past, therefore `is` would not be correct as it is referring to the present tense. `was`, however, is referring to the past, so it would make sense. An example of where you would use `is` is `Neil Armstrong is the only person to step on the moon` if Neil Armstrong, to this day is the only person to ever step on the moon.

Comment: "... is the first person to **have stepped** on the moon."